# Best way to retrieve database results for further use?

Tags: python, sql

I am working heavily with a database, using python, and I am trying to write code that actually makes my life easier.

Most of the time, I need to run a query and get results to process them; most of the time I get the same fields from the same table, so my idea was to collect the various results in an object, to process it later.

I am using SQLAlchemy for the DB interaction. From what I can read, there is no direct way to just say "dump the result of this query to an object", so I can access the various fields like

```
print object.fieldA
print object.fieldB
```

and so on. I tried dumping the results to JSON, but even that require parsing and it is not as straightforward as I hoped.

So at this point is there anything else that I can actually try? Or should I write a custom object that mimic the db structure, and parse the result with for loops, to put the data in the right place? I was hoping to find a way to do this automatically, but so far it seems that the only way to get something close to what I am looking for, is to use JSON.

EDIT:
Found some info about serialization and the capabilities that SQLAlchemy has, to read a table and reproduce a sort of 1:1 copy of it in an object, but I am not sure that this will actually work with a query.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the best way is to actually use a custom object.

You can use reflection trough SQLAlchemy to extrapolate the structure, but if you are dealing with a small database with few tables, you can simply create on your own the object that will host the data. This gives you control over the object and what you can put in it.

There are obvious other ways, but since nobody posted anything; I assume that either are too easy to be mentioned, or too hard and specific to each case.